# PHP string comparison with special letters

Tags: php, arrays, string, string-comparison, strcmp

I have an array of attributes which taken from woocommerce store using rest api. It looks like:

```
Array
 (
 [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 6
        [name] => Modelis
        [position] => 0
        [visible] => 1
        [variation] => 1
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 5
        [name] => Krāsa
        [position] => 1
        [visible] => 1
        [variation] => 1
    )

)
```

In this array I want to find item with name 'Krāsa'. As it contains special letters 'ā', simple comparison doesnt work:

```
foreach ($attributes as $item):
  if (!strcmp($item->name, 'Krāsa')):
    print_r('Names match');
  endif;
endforeach;
```

Such if clause is always false although there is name Krāsa in the array. Maybe that's my poor background, but I would like to know, how to properly compare such strings?

Many thanks.

Comment: hmm, if I run `!strcmp('Krāsa', 'Krāsa')` the result is true.

Comment: How about use `htmlspecialchars` before the compare on the strings?

Comment: ^ `strcmp` return 0 if they are the same so OK to use `!`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In some cases, when you're having trouble with the encoding of your strings, you can convert your strings encoding.

```
foreach ($attributes as $item):
    if (strcmp(mb_convert_encoding($item->name, 'utf-8', 'auto'), mb_convert_encoding('Krāsa', 'utf-8', 'auto')) == 0):
        print_r('Names match');
      endif;
    endforeach;
```

Comment: Well this is what I was thinking. But in my case your if is never true. That's the problem. It works for attributes without special letters. But for word 'Krāsa' the `mb_convert_encoding` outputs 'Krāsa' from `$item->name` and 'Kr?sa' from hardcoded string. I suppose utf-8 is not correct encoding here..

Comment: The second parameter is to set your current encoding. You can see your current encoding by using: `echo mb_detect_encoding($str);`